# What is the Dark Force Defence League?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* Gilderoy Lockhart mentions the existence of the Dark Force Defence League, of which he is apparently an honorary member.

> "Gilderoy Lockhart, Order of Merlin, Third Class, Honorary Member of the Dark Force Defence League and five times winner of Witch Weekly's Most-Charming-Smile Award..."
>   <sub>*(Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 6, Gilderoy Lockhart)*.</sub>

As I recall, there's another reference to them in a Rita Skeeter article where a Dark Force Defence League member says that it's concerning that Harry can speak Parseltongue.

Do we know anything else about this organisation? Is it really serious about fighting Dark wizards? If so, why do we never see them coordinating more with other resistance groups like the Order of the Phoenix during Voldemort's reign of terror?

Answer (score 4):

## Who knows.

This is the only time that they are mentioned, aside from in the Daily Prophet in GoF, where they quoted a wizard from the organization.  Nothing about them is known.

> "Me," he said, pointing at it and winking as well. "Gilderoy Lockhart, Order of Merlin, Third Class, Honorary Member of the Dark Force Defence League and five times winner of Witch Weekly's Most-Charming-Smile Award - but I don't talk about that. I didn't get rid of the Bandon Banshee by *smiling* at her!"
> <sub>-The Chamber of Secrets, chapter 6: Gilderoy Lockhart</sub>

---

> Parseltongue, the ability to converse with snakes, has long been considered a Dark Art. Indeed, the most famous Parselmouth in our times is none other than You-Know-Who himself. A member of the Dark Force Defense League, who wished to remain unnamed, stated that he would regard any wizard who could speak Parseltongue "as worthy of investigation. Personally, I would be highly suspicious of anybody who can converse with snakes, as serpents are often used in the worst kind of Dark Magic, and are historically associated with evildoers."
> <sub>-The Goblet of Fire, chapter 21: The Third Task</sub>

Comment: My take on it was that they were weekend warriors, a sort of wannabe Order of the Phoenix but more of a Neighbourhood Watch scheme.

Comment: We get a fair amount of detail on the Ministry, so we can be fairly sure they're not an official part of that. Maybe a sort of retired Aurors club!